# More database traffic than the DataSet?

Tags: asp.net

Forget the other details of the DataSet vs DataReader argument and tell me **factually** whether using the DataSet saves you from creating as many database queries as the DataReader does?

In my experience, it is clear that using the DataReader requires more database queries than using a DataSet. With the DataSet you can create one query (or stored procedure), disconnect, and then simply query the DataSet, leaving less back-and-forth to the database.

So factually, is the statement true that a DataReader creates more database traffic than a DataSet given the same scenario of cause.

Comment: I'm certain this will piss you off, but IT DEPENDS.

Comment: DataReader is using connected environment but DataSet is used in disconnected environment. DataSet stored the data in client memory bt DataReader read/write data from database that's why you need to make the connection open while using DataReader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DataSet` **uses** a `DataReader` to populate itself.

So the answer is no, a `DataReader` does not create more database traffic. It is the developer's understanding and usage (or mis-usage) that would create more database traffic.

Comment: Now here's a smart person, but does it always use a DataReader, and the times that it does not use a DataSet it would certainly need to go-back-and forth for each separate database query?

Comment: Yes it always uses a DataReader. BTW, you can always return multiple queries from one DataReader too. No matter how you get data from the DB, it will always iterate over each record once right? All a DataSet does is save you the extra step of manually disconnecting the data from the connection.

Comment: Perhaps I should use an example:

Comment: Yes please. Edit your original answer. I'm looking forward to it.

Comment: Perhaps I should use an example: If I fill a dropdownlist with items, and I have a movenext and moveprevious navigation buttons to display an image for each selected item. With just a DataReader, when I step-into I can see that each time I move next or previous, I need to access the database to run the stored procedure. What happens if I fill a DataSet? Would I be able do a move next and previous without having to access the database each time?

Comment: What you are describing is not the difference between a DataRepeater and a DataSet. It is the difference between 1) getting all your results once on initial page load and accessing it for each postback and 2) getting only the information you need each time you need it. It is more an issue of design than the differences between DataRepeater and DataSet. That make sense?

Comment: I am not entirely sure I get it, so how do I retain my data for the movenext/previous scenario I mentioned?

Comment: Let me know when you will be available, we should probably continue this in the chat room. It will be a lot easier.